# Format Exception Error Double INVALID IN New-Transaction class

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

**When supply value in input field double and hit button ADD NEW transaction it gives me Error Exception occur double Invalid**

The idea of this project is This is a project about expenses user supply two value item name and price of the item and this item will add in a list and show on the screen is a list Everything is going well but only one error or exception

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NewTransaction extends StatelessWidget {
  //NewTransaction({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  //@override
  //State<NewTransaction> createState() => _NewTransactionState();
  final Function addTx;
  final titleController = TextEditingController();
  final amountController = TextEditingController();
  NewTransaction(this.addTx, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 10,
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            TextField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Enter Title',
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 25,
                  )),
              // onChanged: (value) {
              //   inputtitle = value;
              // },
              controller: titleController,
            ),
            TextField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Enter Amount',
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 25)),
              //One of this method to save value in a field but we try another method
              // onChanged: (value) {
              //   inputamount = value;
              // },
              controller: amountController,
            ),
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  //using lisnter mentod i confirm this way my value is save or not
                  // print(inputtitle);
                  // print(inputamount);
                  // print(titleController.text);
                  addTx(
                    titleController.text,
                    double.parse(amountController.text),
                  );
                },
                child: Text('Add Transaction',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.purple)))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Format Exception Error: Invalid Double](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5d4k.png)

**User Transaction class**

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import '../modals/transactions.dart';
import 'new_transaction.dart';
import 'transaction_list.dart';

class UserTransactions extends StatefulWidget {
  const UserTransactions({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UserTransactionsState createState() => _UserTransactionsState();
}

class _UserTransactionsState extends State<UserTransactions> {
  final List<TranSaction> _userTransactions = [
    TranSaction(
      id: 't1',
      title: 'New Shoes',
      amount: 69.99,
      date: DateTime.now(),
    ),
    TranSaction(
      id: 't2',
      title: 'Weekly Groceries',
      amount: 16.53,
      date: DateTime.now(),
    ),
  ];

  void _addNewTransaction(String txTitle, double txAmount) {
    final newTx = TranSaction(
      title: txTitle,
      amount: txAmount,
      date: DateTime.now(),
      id: DateTime.now().toString(),
    );

    setState(() {
      _userTransactions.add(newTx);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        NewTransaction(_addNewTransaction),
        TransactionList(_userTransactions),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:budget/modals/transactions.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class TransactionList extends StatefulWidget {
  const TransactionList(List<TranSaction> userTransactions, {Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TransactionListState createState() => _TransactionListState();
}

class _TransactionListState extends State<TransactionList> {
  final List<TranSaction> _userTransacton = [
    TranSaction(
        id: 't1', title: 'New Shoes', amount: 69.9, date: DateTime.now()),
    TranSaction(
        id: 't2',
        title: 'Weekly Groceries',
        amount: 16.53,
        date: DateTime.now())
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: _userTransacton.map(
        (tx) {
          return Card(
              child: Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                margin:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 30),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.purple, width: 2)),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Text(
                  //we use here string interpolation to output dollor sign
                  '\$${tx.amount}',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.purple,
                      fontSize: 25),
                ),
              ),
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    tx.title,
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    DateFormat('y/m/d').format(tx.date),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueGrey, fontSize: 15),
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          ));
        },
      ).toList(),
    );
  }
}

class TranSaction {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final double amount;
  final DateTime date;
  TranSaction(
      {required this.id,
      required this.title,
      required this.amount,
      required this.date});
}
```

Comment: What is the string that `double.parse` fails to parse?

Comment: I am using the text-editing controller  is equal to double amount when user enter amount in a text field it capture

Comment: When you get the exception, what is the exact string that it's failing on?  Clearly it isn't a string that represents a `double` amount.